# How Create SQLite database in a tauri TS app?

Tags: typescript, sqlite, rust, database-connection, tauri

Docs of tauri are still trash. I can only find tutorials in the internet about setting up a node ts server for web projects with sqlite. Does anybody know how I can do that? Assuming a boilerplate app that gets generated in the beginning after setup quick start guide. Where am I supposed to create the db? In the tauri rust or ts part?

I wan't to store passwords in the database because I'm building a password generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where am I supposed to create the db? In the tauri rust or ts part?

From the [`tauri`](https://docs.rs/tauri/1.2.4/tauri/) docs:

> Tauri is a framework for building tiny, blazing fast binaries for all major desktop platforms. Developers can integrate any front-end framework that compiles to HTML, JS and CSS for building their user interface. The backend of the application is a rust-sourced binary with an API that the front-end can interact with.

The TS part is meant to handle your frontend-related stuff, invoking Tauri [commands](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/features/command), which are basically Rust functions. To answer your question, you should handle database interactions in the Rust part of your Tauri app, exposing an API that can be used by the TS part of your app that handles rendering the data.

Comment: Thanks for answering! As I see you're a rust developer. I'm new to it. Should I do the connection and querys in the main.rs file or make a seperate file for it? What is the best practice in a tauri app?

Comment: I'd establish a database connection pool in your main function and pass it to [`Builder::manage`](https://docs.rs/tauri/latest/tauri/struct.Builder.html#method.manage). Then I'd write commands where you create your queries for each operation you have to perform. So for example one command for creating a password, one for deleting it, etc. Whether I'd put them in another file depends on the complexity and amount of operations, but I'd start writing them in my `main.rs` and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Tauri has an official plugin `tauri-plugin-sql` for managing database operations, whether you plan on using sqlite, mysql or postgres. I'd look into it: https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri-plugin-sql

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.